# Installing patched version of R 3.4.0 on ubuntu

Tags: r, ubuntu, sweave

When R upgraded to 3.4.0, a bug was introduced (Sweave commands exit 1 on success, rather than 0), which has broken all my reporting make files. I can fiddle with the make files to fix them, but a patched version of 3.4.0 has been released (see https://cran.r-project.org/, "CHANGES IN R 3.4.0 patched", and I would like to upgrade my R installation to get this fix.

I am using R on ubuntu (xenial), with this line in my apt sources file: 
`deb http://cran.stat.auckland.ac.nz/bin/linux/ubuntu xenial/`.  I have run `sudo apt update` but no fixes for R have come through since 3.4.0 was released.

The question is, what is the "right" way to install the patched R?

Comment: You need to get those in charge of those binaries to replace the "pristine" R 3.4.0 with R 3.4.0 "patched".  That does not happen automagically.

Comment: Thanks Dirk!  This is definitely the solution that would help the most people. I will email r-devel and see what happens  ....

Comment: The r-devel list has very little to do with that.  Maybe try r-sig-debian.

Comment: In the meantime, I am putting the following line in to my make files:
```R CMD Sweave $< 2>&1 | tee /dev/tty | grep Error | exit `wc -l` ```